# Specflow - Using the same step def for any keyword

Tags: c#, .net, bdd, specflow

How do I use a step definition in a feature file where the starting keyword can be any of Given/When/Then

example:

Feature file

```
Given I do something
When I do something else
Then blah blah
And I do something else
```

How do I write just the 1 step definition to deal with the 2 x "I do something else".  As far as I can tell right now I have to write 2 x identical step definitions to deal with this

Currently I have to do this in the Step Def file

```
[When(@"I do something else"]
public blah()
{
do something
}

[Then(@"I do something else"]
public blah2()
{
do something
}
```

Comment: I believe if you use Given, When, Then as they are intended to be used, it rarely makes sense to interchange the starting keyword. "I do something" would go with "When"; "Given" is followed by "something exists"; "Then" is followed by "I observe something"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put multiple attributes on the same method.
So in your case it would look like this:

```cs
[When(@"I do something else"]
[Then(@"I do something else"]
public void blah()
{
// do something
}
```

If you want that a step is for all 3 parts (Given/When/Then), you can use the `StepDefinitionAttribute`.

In that case it looks like this:

```cs
[StepDefinition(@"I do something else"]
public void blah()
{
// do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  The [StepDefinition(@ is a game changer - thank you.